# Unable to access jar file when trying to execute external jar as Process

Tags: java

Well netbeans Java 7u17 project. I'm trying to execute an external jar file that has dependencies on the following way:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"java", "-jar", String.format("%s %s", path, cmde)});
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

And when I execute this application I get the following error message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/SampleApplication/ProcessTest/proc.jar -k
```

The jar file has its depenedcies (other jar files) right next to it in a folder called lib. When I open up PowerShell or Command Prompt and manually enter

```
java -jar C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/SampleApplication/ProcessTest/proc.jar -k
```

The application is executed flawlessly. Why not from my java application? I tried numerous answers for similar problem from stack overflow but none of them worked. Some example:
 - Restarted netbeans
 - Closed & Reopened project
 - Rebuilt proc.jar

thanks for every help
 - Joey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not solve it neither, but I have a workaround.
Create a bat script which runs your jar and execute that bat file like:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\...\\runproc.bat");
```

**EDIT:**

You need to split the command arguments one by one, like:

```java
ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", path, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Comment: Actually I can't create a bat because i don't know on what kind of operating systems the application will run. I've chosen JAVa because it is said to be cross platform, but it seems quite the opposite so far. :-/

Comment: try this: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", path, cmde);

Comment: Oh my god. This actually looks very promising. Now the applications runs, but seems like command line arguments with values are broken. I think I can handle that.

Comment: just enumerate the arguments each in a separate string argument, like ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", path, arg1, arg2, ...)

Comment: Found the solution. You have to split the whole command to parts like:
String[] cmd = command.split(" ");
works flawlessly :o

Can you edit your answer to your latest comment so I can accept it as solution? Since that answers my question fully. And Thank you very much for your help. You really saved me a couple days. :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the answer, I can't make comments yet, but maybe you should use:

```
//This is correct
String path = "C:\\xxx\\xxx";
//This is incorrect
String path = "C:/xxx/xxx";
```

I'm just assuming, since your output shows "/" instead of the windows standard "\".

Comment: Both are correct. As I said If i type java -jar C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/SampleApplication/ProcessTest/proc.jar -k in PowerShell proc.jar gets executed without errors.

Comment: I don't know anything about PowerShell, but maybe you should try executing it the way you did in Powershell, except in a native console.  I have an assumption that PowerShell may swap the "/" for a "\".  It's just a guess.  Edit:  Nevermind, I see you said that you ran it in a native console like that already.

Comment: Also, just for reference, any type of path used in Java, for Windows, needs to have two "\".  You can't run commands using a path with "/" for Windows in Java, since it isn't standard.  Only for *nix systems do you use "/".

Comment: Java takes care of / internally. Windows, Unix, Mac you use everywhere the / sign. Even in C it works the same. For cross-platform you use / even in windows, and it will work. Just like it works in my case on a Windows Server 2012 Datacenter and Fedora 14.

Comment: Maybe I'm incorrect, but I've always used it that way and it works.  Anyways, best of luck to you in your search for an answer!

Comment: Already solved, refer to the comments  under Dmitri Carpov's answer.
Only needed to split the command along space chars.